# Sharepoint Site Slows Down When User Logged In

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, performance

when i visit my sharepoint site an anonymous user, every page loading in few seconds, but when i logged in, pages are loading in 15-20 seconds. Do you have any idea for solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: i am using google chrome.

Comment: as an anon user, it is probably loading significantly less javascript and other assets/code, is there anything custom in place for authenticated users?

Comment: Or you have different cache profiles for anonymous and other users

Comment: no, there is nothing custom in place for authenticated users

Comment: i didn't do anything about cache profiles

Answer (score 0):

You might be having some files in draft mode which has some script that is slowing the page down or you are referring a resource files from other site which is not available.

Answer (score 0):

The answers so far have a lot of merit but to answer "why" we can only speculate.

Here's how you can find out:

- install Fiddler on your client - http://www.telerik.com/fiddler
- record two traces, one while logged in and one while browsing anonymously.
- compare the traces:

a.) You might see more files in the longer load than in the slower.

b.) Use Fiddler's "Timeline" view to see how long it takes for each element of the page to load. And don't just check the .aspx part of the page, highlight all of the page elements including images, js, css, etc.

---

Another way to test page performance is to enable Developer Dashboard, which requires server access and running PowerShell. Fiddler shows performance from perspective of the client web browser but Dev Dashboard can show perf from perspective of the server. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn449110.aspx#DeveloperDashboard

Answer (score 0):

Tools which you can make use of

> Google page speed
>
> Google page load [it's a add-on]
>
> Fiddler is the best

Make sure Compression is enabled. Check minification is done for static .js,.css files

Caching is implemented in SharePoint